# Create a new Google_maps.api.xml file without creating a new Maps activity?

Tags: android, google-maps, android-studio, google-maps-android-api-2, api-key

I am using the Google Maps API in one of my Android Studio projects right now and I made a duplicate copy of the project. However, when working on the copy, my Google  Maps API key doesn't work because it still refers to the original copy of the project(the copy has a different package name than the original).

So right now I have the original project's `google_maps_api.xml` in my copy project, with the copy project still referring to the original project's package name and SHA-1 certificate despite my copy having a different package name. Is it possible to generate a new `google_maps.api.xml` file without creating another `MapsActivity` so that I can get a new API key for the duplicate version of my Android project?

Comment: just add the package name & signature to the restrictions (or exclusions thereof) to the API key.